# Align two tables withone one misplacing another

Tags: html, css

I've tried to look at a few web pages but none of them seem to be addressing the specific issue I'm having. I'm trying to make a web page and I'm trying to make a table aligned to the left side of the web page with while the rest in center aligned. However the items ligned in the center are pushed over to the right where the left aligned table is. How can I align something in the center without it being interefered with something aligned on the left side of the page?
Here is my code.

```
`<!doctype html>
<title> Webpage.</title>
<body>
<body background="Data/Back.jpg">
    <table style="float: left" bgcolor="#9999FF" border="solid">
    <tr>
    <th><ul><h1>Directory.</h1></ul></th></tr>
    <br>
    <tr><td><li><a href="subpages/skills.html">Skills.</li></td></tr>
    <tr><td><li><a href="subpages/experience.html">Experience.</li></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td><li><a href="subpages/References">References.</li></td></tr>
    <tr><td><li><a href="subpages/ContactInfo.html">Contact Info.</li>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td><li><a href="subpages/Resume.html">Resume.</li></td></tr>
    </table>
<center>
    <table bgcolor="CCCCCC" border="3px solid black">
    <tr>
    <th><h1><b><u>Name/Header.</u></b></h1></th>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <img src="Data/Me.jpg" width="25%">
    <table bgcolor="#819FF7" width="50%" border="solid">
        <tr>
        <th>About me.</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Subject
        </td>
        </tr>
    </center>
<style type="text/css">
    h1{
        color: #0404B4
    }
    th{
        color: #61380B
}
td{
        color: #8A0829
    }
</style>
</body>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove `float: left` from the first table. Floating an element means that other elements will attempt to occupy any remaining width when that element is less than 100% of the width of the parent. Alternatively, **clear** the floats afterwards with `clear: both`.

Here's an example, cleanly formatted, and removing `float: left`.

```css
h1 {
  color: #0404B4;
}

th {
  color: #61380B;
}

td {
  color: #8A0829;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table bgcolor="#9999FF" border="solid">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <div style="margin-left: 2em">
          <h1>Directory.</h1>
        </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="subpages/skills.html">Skills.</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="subpages/experience.html">Experience.</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="subpages/References">References.</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="subpages/ContactInfo.html">Contact Info.</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="subpages/Resume.html">Resume.</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <center>
    <table bgcolor="#CCCCCC" border="3px solid black">
      <tr>
        <th>
          <h1><b><u>Name/Header.</u></b></h1>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table><img src="Data/Me.jpg" width="25%">
    <table bgcolor="#819FF7" border="solid" width="50%">
      <tr>
        <th>About me.</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Subject</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first webpage I'm making as I just started with HTML today. o.o Your code is so much prettier than mine. Thank you for showing how I should make mine more functional and elegant on top of helping me fix my issue.

Comment: No problem! Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things flowing smoothly :)